# How to align 3 span in one line horizontaly?

Tags: css

How should I keep the `yellowarea` in middle of `redarea` and `greenarea`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ashish3506/4wopk1u3/1/

My HTML code

```
<body>
<span class="redarea"></span> 
<span class="yellowarea"></span> 
<span class="greenarea"></span>
</body>
```

My CSS Code

```
.redarea{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:red;
float:left;
}

.yellowarea{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:yellow;
margin-left:400px;
}

.greenarea{
float:right;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this

```
span {  
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.redarea{
    background:red;
}

.yellowarea{
    background:yellow;
}

.greenarea{
    background:green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/theprog/4wopk1u3/7/

Comment: This is the solution i need, Thanks Shimul

Answer (score 1):

Check code once

```css
.redarea{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background:red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.yellowarea{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.greenarea{
width:200px;
height:300px;
background:green;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
   
<body>
<span class="redarea"></span> 
<span class="yellowarea"></span> 
<span class="greenarea"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the floats and margins and add `display:inline-block`

```
.redarea {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.yellowarea {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}

.greenarea {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Note: This does not resize the blocks for a smaller screen, so on JS Fiddle, it will appear that they stack. If the width of the page is sufficient for 900px, then they will appear side by side.